# Sending Notification from a timer handler cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a timer which was started by main thread. From timer handler I am sending notification
In 1 out of 5 cases, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when the post notification code is executed.

```
//Registering Notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(TestNotification:)
                   name:@"TestNotification" object:nil];

//Starting timer
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2
                                                 target:self 
                                               selector:@selector(timerhandler:) 
                                               userInfo:nil 
                                                repeats:YES];    


    //Posting notification from timer handler    
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]   
             postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" object:nil];
```

Can someone help.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the `TestNotification:` method. The problem is most likely there.

Answer (score 1):

At first it looks like an object that have `registered` to receive notification didn't `unregister` before getting `deallocated`.
Resulting in the Notification center sending a message to a deallocated object.

But without more code it's hard to say more.